# WCF/.NET - Filter characters not supported by the charset of a legacy target system

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, mainframe, websphere

We have to deal with a legacy system that has a different restricted charset ([CCSID 1148](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_500)) from our .NET main system that supports *UTF-8/UTF-16*.
The main system talks to the legacy system using WCF with a web service; the logic of what happens behind the web service can't be modified because it is handled by the transaction service, what we generally see is that the unsupported character contained for example in a String is stored in the target system replaced by a [SUB character (x001A)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character).
This substitution behaviour is what IBM calls "[Enforced subset conversion](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/char/src/tpc/db2z_enforcedsubsetconversion.html)".
The SUB character is then a problem because is not a valid character in XML and it can't be read back by other systems.

What we can do is to filter and sanitize the strings of the .NET object passed to WCF before the call; the .NET object could be a complex object with several nested levels.
One strategy could be in serializing the object to XML, replacing the not supported characters on the legacy system, serialize back to the .NET object and invoke the web service; this could work but it means some overhead in the call.
Another solution would be to extend the WCF XML1.0 datacontract, removing the offending characters in some way.

Do you have any other strategy to handle a scenario like this?

Comment: Use a different substitution character.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that would be fantastic but I don't know if it is possible in a given charset.

Comment: Is this character set *completely* incompatible with XML?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the overhead.   Replacing the characters is going to be a tiny proportion of the overall processing time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey X001A is sadly incompatible with XML.

Comment: OK.  I assume somewhere you're converting to UTF-16 or some form of unicode?

Comment: Is it better trying to extend the datacontract with a strip rule or trying to apply a strip filter just before the HTTP invocation?

Comment: How do you define "better?"

Comment: sounds like the data should be coming across binary and your system should handle the EBCIDIC to UTF-8 conversion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the IBM transaction do this Enforced subset conversion by itself, I added the link for reference.

Comment: So you could simply replace the incompatible character with some other UTF-16 character that is compatible, in the most expedient way available?

Comment: @RobertHarvey given that the subsitution is enforced by the transaction server, the most expedient way is to do the  substitution when we receive the wcf response (but as I said, the data object received can be complex).

Comment: Right.  But if it's simply a string substitution, it doesn't matter how complex it is, does it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey uhm, imagine a complex object with nested data with other objects and several "layer"; how could you navigate through this entire object three to strip the offending characters that could be anywhere (Strings, String arrays, etc etc.)?

Comment: XML is a string, right?

Comment: Are you saying it's not even getting that far?

Comment: @RobertHarvey yeah, XML is a string. That's why I'm thinking to serialize it and strip from it or strip from data contract or strip just before sending the data over HTTP.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have to decide which is the most convenient way to strip it in WCF. Extending the datacontract seems legit to me.

Comment: All it takes is code.